# Fitting data into ODE system/model in c/c++

Tags: c++, ode

I've got an Octave program that fits experimental data into a model of different ODEs. The Octave program uses the leasqr() function to fit the data.

My task is to reimplement this in C++, but I haven't found any library, which provides a similar function. ALG and GSL both provide functions to simulate an ODE system without experimental data, or fit data into a single ODE.

The ODE system look like that:

```
dA/dt = -k1*A
dB/dt = k1*A-k2*B-k3*B
dC/dt = k3*B-k4*C
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem or what library to use? I can't imagine that this is possible in Octave (or R), but nobody has accomplished that before in C++.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice question but off-topic here, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Of course it is possible in R, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/7448/solving-odes-in-r)

Comment: @J_F thanks, I know that it is possible with other languages, but I've to stick with c++